# Can I export View NX2 Custom Settings?

Tags: nikon, software

Is there a way to export the `Custom Settings for Adjustments Palette` that I used in the editor view of NX2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer seems to be for Capture NX2 which does not answer the original question which appears to be for View NX2 a different program.  So, the answer as far as I know is, NO you cannot save anything in View NX2 related to edits except Picture Control profiles.

Answer (score 4):

With all 3 Develop edit panes, and the Adjust edit pane, closed, control-click in the space beneath the closed Adjust pane.  You will see a contextual menu appear, where you can save (and load) settings.

This copies settings from all Develop and Adjust panes, but you can save/copy after editing only those settings that you want to apply later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of [my scripts](http://rokdd.de/permanent:viewnx2-patch-adjustments) for copying adjustments might help you to export to other images.

Edit: The one batch allows to copy the nikon adjustments to a cache file. The another batch copies back to a bunch of files and adjust nikon settings. So it is an export like you might want, It depends where you want to export..

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do your scripts do exactly, and how might they help?